# How to merge duplicates as new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to merge to dataframes on 1 column for which I would like the output of duplicates to be an extra column instead of a new row.

What happens now:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0'],
                     'B': ['B0']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A0'],
                     'C': ['C4', 'C5']})

df1.merge(df2, on = 'A', how = 'left')
```

Gives the output:

```
    A   B   C
0  A0  B0  C4
1  A0  B0  C5
```

What I would like the output to be:

```
    A   B   C_1   C_2
0  A0  B0  C4    C5
```

Thanks!

Comment: After reading this [page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) it seems there is no straightforward way to do it. This is mainly because duplicates are row oriented not column oriented. As `@jezrael` shows in its answer, it boils down to flatten into a single row and then join on key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create unique values of column `A` in `df2` by `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with counter column by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and flatten `Multiindex` by `map` with `join`::

```
df2 = df2.set_index(['A', df2.groupby('A').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)]).unstack()
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('_'.join)
df2 = df2.reset_index()
print (df2)
    A C_1 C_2
0  A0  C4  C5

df = df1.merge(df2, on = 'A', how = 'left')
print (df)
    A   B C_1 C_2
0  A0  B0  C4  C5
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line of code:

```
df1.merge(df2.assign(Cs=range(0,len(df2))).pivot(index='A',columns='Cs'),on='A')

    A   B (C, 0) (C, 1)
0  A0  B0     C4     C5
```